# App works in ios simulator, but changes to index.ios.js not showing up

Tags: react-native

I just installed react-native and did:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I've opened the project in xcode (version 7.2), and clicked the run button.  The build completed and the app launched in a simulator.

I turned on live reloading and made a simple edit to "index.ios.js", but the change did not show up.  I even closed the simulator, cleaned the project, and rebuilt and relaunched it.  Still, the change did not show up.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does Command+R reload it manually?

Comment: Make sure the index.ios.js file you're editing is the one running in the simulator. I know this seems obvious, but I've caught myself working on a file I *thought* was the working file, but actually wasn't.

Comment: I'm editing the one in the root of "AwesomeProject"

Comment: but is it the same AwesomeProject running in the simulator? Try creating another project with a totally new/different name... and running/editing that.

Comment: Ugh, that was it.  Sometimes the answer is to open your mind to the depth of your own stupidity :)  Thanks.

Comment: haha, we've all been there. glad you're back on track

Comment: Go ahead and add you answer to the comments, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the index.ios.js file you're editing is the same one running in the simulator. I know this seems obvious, but I've caught myself working on a file I *thought* was the file in the simulator but actually wasn't.